# Can't compile any c program (/usr/bin/ld: 1: Syntax error: newline unexpected)

Tags: make, c, gcc, dynamic-linking

*Hello everyone,*

I have a serious issue, i can't compile any c program, i get the following error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: 1: Syntax error: newline unexpected
collect2: ld returned 2 exit status
```

I have found on the net this solution but it doesn't work for me :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove binutils    
sudo apt-get install binutils
```

*Any tips for this please ?*

I was doing some FairThreads in C, so i got to use the lib -lfthread. And i used a make file which has his LIB_DIR at usr/bin/ld

I runned a make command and that was probably what caused all this... This is what the make file contains :

```
INCL_DIR    = ../include
LIB_DIR     = usr/bin/ld

##############################################################
MAKE        = make
CC      = gcc
AR      = ar
RANLIB      = ranlib

##############################################################
LIBS        = -lfthread -lpthread
#LIBS       = -lposix4 -lfthread -lpthread # for solaris

##############################################################
##############################################################
CFLAGS      = -Wall -O3 -D_REENTRANT

############ Basic libraries #################################
LIB_NAME    = fthread
LIBFT           = lib$(LIB_NAME).a

############ C code to executable code ########################
.c.o :
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

############ The h files ######################################
HFILES        = fthread.h fthread_internal.h \
                event.h thread.h scheduler.h \
                broadcastlist.h locklist.h threadlist.h \
                environment.h trace.h verify.h

############ The C files ######################################
CFILES        = event.c thread.c scheduler.c \
                broadcastlist.c locklist.c threadlist.c \
                environment.c automaton.c instruction.c

############ The object files ##################################
OBJS          = event.o thread.o scheduler.o \
                broadcastlist.o locklist.o threadlist.o \
                environment.o automaton.o instruction.o

############ Make entries ######################################
all: lib

lib: $(HFILE) $(OBJS)
    $(AR) r $(LIBFT) $(OBJS)
    - $(RANLIB) $(LIBFT)

install: lib
    cp $(LIBFT) $(LIB_DIR)
    cp fthread.h $(INCL_DIR)

clean:
    - rm -rf *.o *~ $(LIBFT) a.out

############ Auxiliary ########################################
TEST        = test.c

lines:
    wc -l $(CFILES) $(HFILES)

test:all
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I. -L. $(TEST) $(LIBS)
    a.out

############ Dependencies ########################################
$(OBJS): $(HFILE)

############ end of makefile #####################################
```

I can normally execute files which are already compiled, but i can't compile anything.

eg :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {printf("Hello world");  return 0;}
```

when i compile this program by the command :

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

I get the same error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: 2: /usr/bin/ld: Syntax error: newline unexpected
collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
```

Comment: What do you get for `cat test.c main(){return 0;}` `gcc test.c`?

Comment: Are you using make? What command line produces this? ld is a linker -- how are you calling it, and with what source and object files? Please flesh out the question properly -- show makefile, and a minimal source, and the command line and output.

Comment: and for the cat, i got the same error !

Comment: This looks as if `/usr/bin/ld` were a script.

Comment: If you get the same message with a simple example, forget the complex options and the makefile. Run `file /usr/bin/ld` and `gcc v test.c` with the above test file and post the output.

Comment: This is what i got for  'file /usr/bin/ld' :

/usr/bin/ld: symbolic link to x86_64-linux-gnu-ld   @RalfFriedl

Comment: On my Linux Mint 19.3, /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld itself is a symbolic link, to /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd. That is the genuine ELF executable (version 2.30, 1783496 bytes).

Comment: how can i fix this @Paul_Pedant

Comment: Try to show the problem in the simplest possible case. [A] Continue down the sequence of symbolic links with `ls -l` until you get to a real file. Run `file` on that. If it says it it ELF, run that name as a command with option --version. Add the whole session verbatim to the question. [B] Write the (well-known) Hello World program. Compile it like `cc Hello.c -o Hello` and run it like `./Hello`. No make, no extra directive, just vanilla. Post all that output in the question too.

Comment: done @Paul_Pedant

Comment: Try [A] too: let's see what program is at the end of those symbolic links -- name, size, permissions, ownership, and version. `ld` should never need to read a text file or parse syntax (which is what the message implies), so it seems likely that whatever is really being run is a script that has overwritten the proper linker code. It would be helpful to see that file's characteristics, and the contents if it is a short text file. That might also be a hint as to how it became damaged.

Comment: Possibly a glimmer of light: the ld linker **does** read text files and throw syntax errors. This question `unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302402/what-is-the-syntax-of-input-in-so-file` has an answer `It's a feature of the GNU linker ld. An input file which isn't in a known binary format is tried as a linker script.` That's the limit of my knowledge, but it may mean something to somebody.

Comment: @roaima I think that is a posting error, because we get as far as /bin/ld, and gcc would choke on this very early. My overnight thought is: there is a rogue file that the linker is reading. Maybe all the compiles are being tried in the same directory. So: `Make a fresh clean directory and try Hello.c in there`. In fact, do that as a new user (in case this is a profile/environment issue).

Comment: up, i added the entire makefile @roaima

Comment: `LIB_DIR = usr/bin/ld` is highly suspicious. Such a path is not expected to be a directory of libraries, but rather an executable. A directory of libraries would generally be named `.../lib`. That said, the error displayed doesn't match an accidental overwriting of the binary `ld` with the `.a` your Makefile is generating, so the truth is out there. BTW, reinstalling binutils can be done with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils` (you forgot the `--reinstall` option)

Comment: when i try to execute the command (reeinstall binutils)  i got errors on : 

linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-image-5.4.0-72-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

@xhienne

Comment: @AmineBenslimane Your installation seems broken (for a reason that is not given in your comment). You must fix it before reinstalling binutils, but this is another unrelated question.

Comment: how can i fix my installation, please ? @xhienne

Comment: @AmineBenslimane This is a whole new question. If/when you open a new question here, add the full details because there is not enough information in your comment to tell you what is going wrong.